# Баг при открытии формы JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

столкнулся  с такой проблемой:формы в JavaFX открываются как-то некорректно. Сначала появляется просто белая форма без ничего, если ее развернуть, то на ней появится изображение. Но оно не будет интерактивным, пока не нажмешь какую-нибудь кнопку вызывающую диалоговое окно. Они тоже прогружаются не с первого раза, нужно открыть, закрыть и снова открыть.

Формы открываю вот так:

```
Button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            Button.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("стиль.fxml"));
            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Parent root = loader.getRoot();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.showAndWait();
        });
```

Диалоговые окна вот так:

```
 Alert exit = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);

            exit.setTitle("Выход");
            exit.setContentText("Вы действительно хотите выйти?");
            exit.setHeaderText(null);
            Optional<ButtonType> option = exit.showAndWait();
```

Как это собственно выглядит:
[image: Форма]
[image: Диалог]

Формы рисую в Scene Builder  и никаких изменений в fxml файлы не вносил.